# Transfer Learning using HuggingFace and Tensorflow with AutoModel does not work

Tags: tensorflow2.0, bert-language-model, huggingface-transformers, transfer-learning

I try to do transfer learning using a `HuggingFace` pretrained BERT model. I want to use tensorflow API with it. I do not understand why the last line produces an error

```py
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModel

model_name = "distilbert-base-uncased"
text = "this is a test"
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)    
text_tensor = tokenizer.encode(text, return_tensors="tf")

model = AutoModel.from_pretrained(model_name).to("cuda")
output = model(text_tensor) # ERROR!!, but why?
```

Comment: What's the error? Stack trace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing Tensorflow and Pytorch.

Use `TFAutoModel` instead of default (Pytorch) `AutoModel`

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, TFAutoModel

model_name = "distilbert-base-uncased"
text = "this is a test"
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)    
text_tensor = tokenizer.encode(text, return_tensors="tf")

model = TFAutoModel.from_pretrained(model_name).to("cuda")
output = model(text_tensor)
```

Comment: Hmm, ok Automodel is for pytorch did not know, thks